# Multi-robots control in ROS2 Humble

Tags: ros2, turtlebot, ros-humble, tf2, multi-robot

I am trying to spawn two robots with the goal of controlling them independently. I have made changes to the empty world launch file in turtlebot3_gazebo package to try and spawn two robots, for now I can spawn two robots with their own topics as seen in the picture below, but I can't get the robots to publish their own odom. [image: tf]

Do someone know what should I do to correct this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a configuration problem. I don't have enough info since we do not see your launch files and config files where you do the remapping, but I'd say you probably forgot to remap the odometry topic according to the namespace.
At least that's what I see from your ROS graph

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am fairly new to this, can you explain how to remap the topic?

Comment: It is difficult to say without looking at your launch file, but I'd suggest you to take a look at [this post](https://discourse.ros.org/t/giving-a-turtlebot3-a-namespace-for-multi-robot-experiments/10756) for reference.